# Insert query where the value gets entered from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

`[utils].[PageContentGroup]`:

```
PageContentGroupId | GroupLabel                             | IsActive
-------------------+----------------------------------------+----------
       253         | Instruction-AdminPlacements(Sessions)  |     1
```

`[utils].[PageContentItem]`:

```
PageContentGroupId | Title         | Text | Color                               | OrderRank | IsActive | Anchor | ReferenceKey
-------------------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------+-------------
        253        | Instructions: | test | alert alert-block bg-green-seagreen |     1     |    1     |   T    | NULL
```

I want to write a query, where I would enter Title, text, color, orderrank, isactive, anchor, referencekey manually in the `[utils].[PageContentItem]` table, but want the primary key of `GroupLabel` (`PageContentGroupId`) from `[utils].[PageContentGroup]` entered automatically into the `[utils].[PageContentItem]` table under `PageContentGroupId`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. (`( select PageContentGroupId from utils.PageContentGroup where GroupLabel = SomethingFromSomewhere and IsActive = 1 )`)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you something, it's like that what you want to do

```
INSERT INTO [utils].[PageContentItem] (PageContentGroupId, Title, Text, Color, OrderRank, IsActive, Anchor, ReferenceKey)
VALUES ( (SELECT TOP 1 PageContentGroupId FROM [utils].[PageContentGroup]), 'Instructions:' , 'test', 'alert alert-block bg-green-seagreen', 1, 1, 'T', NULL)
```